# Mac OS keyboard shortcuts for opening applications

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to Mac and have been surprised from the absence of keyboard shortcuts for opening applications.  According to the instruction (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3957) :” You can’t define keyboard shortcuts for general purpose tasks such as opening an application or switching between applications”.

In Windows assigning keyboard shortcuts for opening applications is very easy. What is the way in Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to ask this question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) instead of stack overflow.

As a preliminary answer, though, a quote from the `Use global keyboard shortcuts` Help text provided by Apple concerning system keyboard shortcuts:

> Note: You can create keyboard shortcuts only for existing menu commands. **You cannot** **define keyboard shortcuts** for general purpose tasks **such as opening an app** or switching between apps.